# What is a substitute for mascarpone cheese?

Tags: substitutions, cheese

I've found mascarpone cheese can be pricey. What would be a good (in taste and price) substitute?

Comment: The specific application would be for a dessert with peaches and mascarpone, using this recipe: http://www.cookstr.com/recipes/peaches-with-mascarpone

Comment: technically speaking, is mascarpone a cheese?

Comment: @Midhat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mascarpone states so

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a highly rated [mascarpone cheese substitute recipe](http://www.food.com/recipe/Substitute-for-Mascarpone-Cheese-28620) on food.com. I haven't personally tried it, but it's highly rated on that site, and is ridiculously simple.

- 1 16 oz block of cream cheese
- 1/2 cup sour cream
- 1/4 cup heavy whipping cream
- Blend until smooth

Try it and let us know? :)

Comment: That is definitely quite like mascarpone! I went ahead and bought mascarpone, despite the cost, as a special treat for some guests. I also mixed up some of this substitute. VERY similar. In fact, my husband didn't like the actual mascarpone b/c he said it tasted like cream cheese.

Comment: @JustRightMenus: Great! I'm glad it worked for you. I'll make sure to use this if I ever need to sub mascarpone.

Comment: I made tiramisu using fat free cream cheese and fat free sour cream in place of the marscapone (I did use the heavy whipping cream) and it turned out great.

Answer (score 7):

8 ounces of full-fat cream cheese blended with 1/4 cup of heavy cream and 2 tablespoons of full-fat sour cream make a decent replacement for mascarpone. A tip: don't try to blend the ingredients when the cream cheese is stone cold!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the application.  Try ricotta (much lower fat, so may not be suitable for some recipes) or a mixture of ricotta and generic cream cheese.

It's pretty easy to make your own ricotta, also, if you want to get into that.

Comment: She said taste and price. Ricotta definitely does not taste like mascarpone. The texture is entirely different as well.

Comment: I agree but based on my experiences ricotta is a good substitute to mascarpone in many recipies, especially desserts. Besides, I'd rather accept a slightly different taste than use some weird mix.

Answer (score 3):

Really, really good thick Greek yoghurt. Might not bake like mascarpone, but it certainly acts like it when you spoon it over a dessert.

Answer (score 2):

I bought some mascarpone and tried the cream cheese (full fat) substitute side by side. Cream cheese was creamier. The mascarpone definitely had a grainier texture, sort of like ricotta. I will play with it a bit, but I think mixing about half and half to 1/3,2/3 ricotta and the cream cheese sour cream mixture would hit it right on the head.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent page that describes how to make your own Mascarpone Cheese with just milk and culture at "http://www.cheesemaking.com/Mascarpone.html"
The cheese is very good, and inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your own? 1 litre of cream makes about 750gm of mascarpone. Pretty easy, but best to have a cooking thermometer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you can make your own?